# Flot data serie with specific color per data element?

Tags: flot

being new to Flot i am struggling a bit. My goal is the present a bar with different data elements in it that must have a different color per element. I want to provide the color per data element.

Any hints on how this can be done?

Example:

```
[0,100][0,200][0,100][0,200]
```

All elements with value 100 should be blue and all elements with 200 should be green.

A nice one would be,

```
[0,100,blue][0,200,green][0,100,blue][0,200,green]
```

But this off course does not work, it is just an explanation what i want to achieve!
Doing this with multiple data series seems does not work in my case.

Any hints on how this can be done?

Comment: Why don't multiple series work for you?

Comment: The data on the indexes vary. Some elements could be missing so the stacking of the series goes wrong.

Comment: I don't see how stacking would prevent you from using multiple series, but you should update the question to match what you're doing.

Comment: @DNS, has a per data point configuration ever been considered?  I see this issue here: https://github.com/flot/flot/issues/283, but I'm thinking something more grand like what highcharts has http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data

Comment: @Mark It's been suggested a few times, but I've never been clear on how it's significantly different from just having multiple series.  It's also not entirely straightforward to implement.  For bars there's no problem, but what do you do with lines/areas; gradients?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with multiple series, as this is how I have done something like this :)

So in your plot method you would have something like this:

```
$.plot($('#placeholder'), []); // The array would hold your data
```

You can also further extend this to provide some options to flot to tell it what to make your chart look like. To do that you pass an object of options after the array.

However, im not quite sure what you need in terms of the Graph, your example gave some numbers but the x coordinate was all 0, im not sure if you just want a bar graph?

Anyway, heres the code of how you would get it to display a bar graph, with one green line and one blue line:

```
var flotOptions = {
    series: {
        lines: { show: true, fill: false, lineWidth: 15 }
    }
},
var data = [{
    color: '#001EFF',
    data: [[0, 0], [0, 100]]
}, {
    color: '#00FF0E',
    data: [[5, 0], [5, 200]]
}];

$.plot($('#placeholder'), data, flotOptions);
```

I would recommend making it so that the data is automatically generated on a server side, then you can check in javascript, and add the `color` depending on the y value in the `data` array of each series.

I have also created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K4det/) of this for you, so you can go take a look and play around with it. As I have said im not quite sure what you want but this is a good start for you. Good luck!!